# How get the value in <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the text in `<tr>`. This is my html code:

```
<table class="table" style="" id="tabella_username_aggiunti">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Cancella</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody_aggiungi_utente"><tr id="aggiungiprova"><td>prova</td><td><button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td></tr></tbody>
      </table>
```

I need to extract the first `<td>` in `<tr>` that is "prova" in this example so I use this jquery code:

```
$('#tbody_aggiungi_utente').children('tr').each(function(i) {
                                            console.log("TABELLA " + JSON.stringify(i)+" Tabella "+JSON.stringify($(this)));
                                            //array_user.push($(this).attr('id').replace('aggiungi', ''));

                                        });
```

But it doesn't work because it prints me `TABELLA 0 Tabella {"0":{},"context":{},"length":1}`

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `$('#tbody_aggiungi_utente').children('tr').each(function() { console.log(this.textContent); });`

Comment: First argument in `callback` function is `index`, not element itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#tbody_aggiungi_utente').children('tr').each(function(i) {
 console.log("TABELLA " + JSON.stringify(i)+" Tabella "+$(this).first().text());
                                            //array_user.push($(this).attr('id').replace('aggiungi', ''));

                                        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" style="" id="tabella_username_aggiunti">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Cancella</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody_aggiungi_utente">
          <tr id="aggiungiprova"><td>prova</td><td><button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `children`.

```
$(this).children('td:eq(0)').html());
```

```js
$('#tbody_aggiungi_utente > tr').each(function(i) {

  console.log("TABELLA " + JSON.stringify(i)+
              " Tabella "+JSON.stringify($(this).children('td:eq(0)').html()));
                                            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" style="" id="tabella_username_aggiunti">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Cancella</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody_aggiungi_utente">
          <tr id="aggiungiprova"><td>prova</td><td><button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td></tr>
          <tr id="aggiungiprova1"><td>prova1</td><td><button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td></tr>
     </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a better selector instead of `children`. Then you need do select the `td` inside your `each`.

```js
$('#tbody_aggiungi_utente tr').each(function(i) {
    var firstTd = $("td:eq(0)", this);
    console.log("TABELLA " + JSON.stringify(i) + " Tabella " + JSON.stringify(firstTd.text()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table" style="" id="tabella_username_aggiunti">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Cancella</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody_aggiungi_utente">
    <tr id="aggiungiprova">
      <td>prova</td>
      <td>
        <button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or you loop the `td's` directly:

```js
$('#tbody_aggiungi_utente tr td:first-of-type').each(function(i) {
    console.log("TABELLA " + JSON.stringify(i) + " Tabella " + JSON.stringify($(this).text()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table" style="" id="tabella_username_aggiunti">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Cancella</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody_aggiungi_utente">
    <tr id="aggiungiprova">
      <td>prova</td>
      <td>
        <button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="aggiungiprova">
      <td>prova 2</td>
      <td>
        <button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `each(function(i)` with `each(function(i,v)` and then `console.log( $(v).text().trim());`

Output will be 'prova'

```js
$('#tbody_aggiungi_utente').children('tr').each(function(i,v) {
  console.log( $(v).text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" style="" id="tabella_username_aggiunti">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Cancella</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_aggiungi_utente">
    <tr id="aggiungiprova">
        <td>prova</td>
        <td>
            <button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). jQuery can select elements using the same methods.

```js
console.log(jQuery("#aggiungiprova td:first-child"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" style="" id="tabella_username_aggiunti">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Cancella</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody_aggiungi_utente">
    <tr id="aggiungiprova">
      <td>prova</td>
      <td>
        <button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```js
a = $('#tabella_username_aggiunti tr th')
console.log(a.text())

//or

a.each(function(a, el) {
  console.log($(el).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" style="" id="tabella_username_aggiunti">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Cancella</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody_aggiungi_utente">
    <tr id="aggiungiprova">
      <td>prova</td>
      <td>
        <button id="eliminaprova" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#aggiungiprova td").first().text();
```

Gives the content of the first td in the tr named "aggiungiprova".

If you need to get all names in the entire list, then:

```
var names = [];

$("#tabella_username_aggiunti tr").each(function(){
    names.push( $("td",this).first().text());
});

// names is now an array of all names
```

Or you name [sic] all name TDs with class and iterate them for easier-to-read code and faster execution:

```
<table>
<tr><td class="name-cell">My Name</td><td>other things</td></tr>
<tr><td class="name-cell">My Name</td><td>other things</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.name-cell').each(function(){
    // $(this).text()
});
```